# Gradient Boosting with a OLS Base Learner

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been playing with the Boostings function in Sklearn and I've noticed a key difference between `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor` and `sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor`.  While the latter allows the user to specify the base learner, the former does not.  Specifically, `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor` only utilize trees. This is a bit annoying, as it would be nice to utilize OLS and Spline base learners within Gradient Boosting.  Am I missing something?  Does another function within the Sklearn library or a different python library offer this functionality?

Comment: Maybe because gradient boosting used in scikit is actually [gradient tree boosting](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#gradient-tree-boosting) and maybe because this is the most common form of [gradient boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting). Other most popular libraries like `xgboost` and [`lightbgm`](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM) also use only trees.

Comment: xgboost allows to use linear learners (use booster='gblinear')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

Replace `sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py` with [this script](https://github.com/Justin-Le/custom-sklearn-gbr/blob/master/gradient_boosting.py).

You'll then be able to pass `base_estimator` to `GradientBoostingRegressor`.

If you're satisfied, please enjoy. If not, please see below for a discussion.

### Demonstration

Before we begin, I'd like to mention a few things. All of the plots in this post can be reproduced from [the scripts available in my repo](https://github.com/Justin-Le/custom-sklearn-gbr) for this project. Simply replace the contents of `restore.sh` and `run.sh` with the appropriate directories for your local installation of Sklearn. Just keep in mind that the two bash scripts will permanently overwrite your existing Sklearn file (`gradient_boosting.py`). You may recover the file by simply copying it from the Sklearn repo. I don't claim that anything demonstrated in this post is good practice for developing new features for Sklearn. I'm not affiliated with Sklearn nor am I an experienced software developer. All scripts were tested on Sklearn 18.2.

Now, using the new `gradient_boosting.py` script, we may specify the linear base learner (as you typically would for `AdaBoostRegressor`). As a sanity check, we may fit the linear-base GBR on a single variable and ensure that it produces a linear visual when plotted against that variable. Here's the result for four (arbitrary) variables from the Boston Housing dataset.

[image: Linear-base GBR fitted to single variables.]

As another sanity check, we may ensure that the results of the original tree-base GBR can be reproduced by passing a tree base_estimator to the new GBR. The following plot is an MSE 10-fold cross-validation profile with respect to the boosting iterations. That is, for each number of boosting iterations, I cross-validate to obtain a vector of 10 MSE scores and compute the mean/min of this vector. The left plot is the original GBR, while the right plot is the one using the new `gradient_boosting.py`.

[image: CV profile for tree-base GBR.]

### What exactly has been changed?

We can [use any diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/WSKSUanQ) to compare the original `gradient_boosting.py` to the new one. This will show you all the steps I took to create this new script, but the main step is to modify the `_fit_stage()` and `_decision_function()` methods. Within `_fit_stage()`, which is responsible for fitting the learner at each boosting iteration, we notice that the base learner (named `tree`) is instantiated with `DecisionTreeRegressor`, so we simply need to add the following conditions in order for this method to use the custom learner specified by the `base_estimator` argument instead:

```
if (self.base_estimator is None or
    isinstance(self.base_estimator,
    (BaseDecisionTree, BaseForest))):

    # Original code for decision trees will go here.

    else:
        base_learner = self.base_estimator

        if X_csc is not None:
            base_learner.fit(X_csc, residual, sample_weight=sample_weight)
        else:
            base_learner.fit(X, residual, sample_weight=sample_weight)

        if X_csr is not None:
            y_pred[:, k] += self.learning_rate * base_learner.predict(X_csr).ravel()
        else:
            y_pred[:, k] += self.learning_rate * base_learner.predict(X).ravel()

        self.estimators_[i, k] = base_learner
```

Next, we may inspect `_decision_function()`, which is responsible for computing the boosted result when the top-level `predict()` function is called from `GradientBoostingRegressor`. Here, the heart of the calculation lies in a function called `predict_stages()`, which is the rather low-level Cython (`.pyx`) implementation of the boosting step intended for the tree-based ensemble only. In order to compute this step for an arbitrary base learner instead, we circumvent the entire `predict_stages()` calculation and enter it manually at the Python level:

```
def _decision_function(self, X):
    score = self._init_decision_function(X)
    score += self.learning_rate*sum(estimator[0].predict(X) for estimator in self.estimators_).reshape((-1, 1))
    # predict_stages(self.estimators_, X, self.learning_rate, score)
    return score
```

The above two changes are what I consider to be the main changes that need to be made. The rest are minor technical details, and they include:

- Showing an error message if feature importances are requested when using a base learner that doesn't include a feature importance method
- Including the base estimator in parameter checking and estimator validation (refer to the original script to see details on these, as I'm not entirely familiar)
- Including the base estimator in the class headers and interfaces (e.g., including the super text in the class definitions for `BaseGradientBoosting` and `GradientBoostingRegressor`)

### What can't be done (yet)?

The base learner that you choose must be able to support a `sample_weights` parameter. For this reason, I was unable to plug in a spline-like regressor (such as PyEarth). Please let me know if you or anyone manages to achieve this.

Also note that when using non-tree base learners, you may still pass tree-related arguments without error, but of course, they will be entirely ignored.

Here are things my script can't (necessarily) do:

- Work with other losses besides the default, `'ls'`. (Perhaps it can, but I haven't tried.)
- Allow `base_estimator` to be passed to `GradientBoostingClassifier`

Overall, this was only a modest beginning toward truly custom base learners. Hope it helps.

Comment: Py-earth does support sample weights now, though it didn't when this answer was written.